# Writing a custom GeoServer WPS process or Data Store

Tags: python, geoserver, wps

I have a third party custom written database that I want to access where I can only return JSON from queries (with a location lat/lon) .  I want to be able to visualize the results on a map. It will have minimal styling associated with it.

Could someone please guide me whether I need to write a custom data store or can I do this with a WPS process?

If possible I'd really like to write this in Python and utilize Geoserver Scripting?  Any tips/tutorials on this?

Comment: Not sure why you would need WPS, for this, WFS would do it too.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using GeoServer I am guessing that you are visualising this on a web map.  A simpler solution would be to just consume the JSON directly in your client web-map code (avoiding the need from Geoserver).  For instance both OpenLayers and Leaflet can do this.  Also, with not too much tweaking you should be able to cast the JSON as proper GeoJSON.  There are some libraries out there (especially if you are going via a Node server) to do this, but it is a very simple matter to 'roll your own' code even client-side to do the conversion.

**EDIT FOLLOWING OP COMMENT:**
I assume that the user is not creating 2 million points in their browser, so I assume that you are being given a database of 2 million points and the need to preprocess this server side becomes both obvious and necessary.  The simplest solution is to preprocess the data into a conventional PostGIS (say) spatial database and publish that through Geoserver.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  Yes, I want to visualize on a map and serve out via GeoServer.  One of the issues I have is that in some cases I want to see the full extent of data which could be about 2 million points.  So I wanted to do everything serverside if possible.